# Automatic recognizing of the proprietary files type

Tags: automation, machine-learning, data-recovery, file-format, deep-learning

I would like have sw/utility/library, what is able to recognize file structures of uknown (proprietary or not so usual) file types.

So I have bunch of files of some proprietary file type (some hundreds or may be thousands of files)

The wanted utility will "eat" them and give me result with some file structure description.

Notice: Particularly I need this information for setting up and tuning the hdd recovery software.

It would be great, if this wanted utility could be able to act as a plugin to 
some recovery software. Or it could be able at least to export some settings for subsequent importing to recovery software.

(I suppose use some usual good recovery softwares, like are rstudio, ufs/rexplorer, stellar, gtdataback, diskdrill, easyus, recuva or similars.....)

Comment: Part of all linuxes: https://linux.die.net/man/1/file It is not AI based, it uses a big database of internal regexp-like binary signatures. With a single-line script can you start a filetype recognition for all sectors of a hard disk.

Comment: Hello @peterh, thank you for interesting hint. But I would need oposite thing: I have bunch of unknown type(s) and I need to process them and extract from them the description of those type(s) - so as I can use that description in some recovery sw (or in magic files of "file(1)" utility e.g.).

Comment: While I would help gladly, I have the impression that you probably you didn't understood the manual. Imho the tool does exactly what you want. Good luck to find the right tool.

Comment: Dear @peterh, making problem  simpler for reason of explanation, I could say: " I would need software, what will generate  "database of internal regexp-like binary signatures" of some proprietary files, not known today by file(1) utility".    I think, it could be better understand now?